# What's that word to describe "technology becoming invisible over time"?

Tags: technology

There is a word similar to *dematerialization* that represents a slightly different concept.

The concept goes something like this: everything eventually becomes invisible.

The concept is particularly evident in technology.  For example, paper was (and still is) an important technology but it is rapidly disappearing.  It's gradually being replaced by computers. So, although the purpose & concept of paper is still around - the physical form is disappearing.

Another example is the horn on a car.   A century ago it was literally a pump you squeezed.   Later the pump was integrated into the center of the steering wheel.  And now, many cars there is no pump at all; it's simply an electronic button.   That is this concept in action.

I want to say *demapherialization* but couldn't find any matches when Googling.   But I do know for a fact there is a Wikipedia entry on it.   The term was dubbed many decades ago.

Anyway, it's a pretty cool concept.  Perhaps someone may know it.

Comment: Some might simply call it **progress**.

Comment: Rather a long time ago, I saw a documentary where they were researching sound effects for cars, such as a clicking turn signal. With today's electronic equipment, there is no longer any natural sound. So they added one. =)

Comment: @TLP See [this](http://www.humansinvent.com/#!/889/5-fake-sounds-designed-to-help-humans/) and [that](http://www.humansinvent.com/#!/936/5-more-fake-sounds-to-fool-you-today/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps you're thinking of *[ephemeralization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeralization)*? (I hesitate because I would have defined it rather differently than you have, so I'm not quite sure it's the concept you're after.)

Comment: Yes, thank-you !   That is the one :)

Comment: Of course. It is a cool concept.